# Type 'AxiosResponse<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'countries[]': length, pop, push, concat

Tags: typescript, axios

On setState I am getting this TS error:

"Type 'AxiosResponse' is missing the following properties from type 'countries[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts(2740)"

Can anyone suggest what's wrong/where to use :countries[] ?

```
export interface IProfileEditorState {
  countries: countries[];
}

interface countries {
  countryID: string;
  countryName: string;
  label: astring;
  value: string;
  isDirector: number;
}

// Temp
public getCountrys() {
axios
.get('https://func-myportal-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/GetCountries?code=j0xGK8L6iRXpZqR3DgaDRoI/H/qjGZSGdBPIY9rZU84uH4SUa80noQ==')
.then(res => {
 this.setState({countries: res});
 })
 // Error catching
 .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every [Axios method](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/c5fe05bdff82e0fa4ace9a832e75052e1ee297f0/index.d.ts#L178) uses [generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) so you can do the following:

```js
axios
  .get<countries>('https://func-myportal-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/GetCountries?code=j0xGK8L6iRXpZqR3DgaDRoI/H/qjGZSGdBPIY9rZU84uH4SUa80noQ==')
  .then(res => { /* res.data here is countries type */ })
```